# Show preview of link target in a tooltip with popup effect

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

## Description of the problem

Many times a post links to another answer.

*Example* :

[image]

So far everything is correct. But what happens if there are several links to a post, and that post contains links to other posts, and so on? One ends up losing context while navigating more and more post links.

## My idea

My idea to debate would be the aggregation of a popup effect where the question / answer of the link is directly visualized, avoiding the exit of the page if you want to make a quick view of the link, and making the user participate if you decide to navigate to the link.

## Graphic description of my idea

[image: Things]

Comment: I normally do that by opening a post in a new window and then open links in its tabs. That keeps context for me and when I'm done I can close a single window that takes all tabs with it. Keep in mind that while hovering works on desktop / mouse gestures. not so much with touch devices. I'm not sure if this feature will be an exciter. Nice to have, sure.

Comment: [iOS has a similar feature built-in](https://ioshacker.com/how-to/3d-touch-gestures-for-safari) – *pressure tap on a link to preview it*

Comment: I'm not a big fan of having my hovers cue a new page request, fwiw, though I get the impetus behind this. If this ever is considered, I'd prefer an option, like a little dropdown button `[v]` to click or something. Also makes it more stable than hover.